# Load a vcalendar from external url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, vcalendar

I want to parse (JavaScript, jquery or php) a vcalendar from a given external url. In a browser if I open this url I have a 'save file .ics' prompt and the file is perfect :(BEGIN:VCALENDAR ...). Ajax not work with external url. I try with a php grabber file (grabber.php)

```
<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); ?>
```

And a simple jquery script

```
$(function(){
    var contentURI= 'https://xxx.xxx.xx/mycalendar';    
    $('#result').load('grabber.php?url='+ contentURI);
});
```

But I see a web page and not the calendar. Any suggest?

Comment: What do you get if you access `grabber.php` directly in the browser?

Comment: i write a dummy url, the real url it's like : 
    https://www.xxx.it/export_calendar.cfm?id=xxx ... 
It's a b&b calendar  ...

If a try to open direct: grabber.php?url= ... i have olso a web page

Comment: Are you logged in to the web site (the calendar site) when you download the .ics through the browser? If yes, then that is most likely your issue; you need to be logged in to be able to access that URL, which your PHP script isn't.

Comment: Yes! This is the problem! Any way to automate login process?

Comment: There's no "generic" way, no. It totally depends on how they have implemented their authorization. It might work if you use cURL to login, store the cookies and then use cURL to access the url, passing the cookies. But if they have some CSRF-protection, it get's tougher. Contact the site owners, they might have some API or similar?

Comment: the problem is they want we use a very expensive channel manager but this is out of topic ...